# Why is for loop executed when the condition should be false?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have the following code :

```
    public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {
      int maxSpan = 0;
      int span;
      int j;
      for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
      {
         for(j = nums.length - 1; nums[i] != nums[j]; j--);
         span = 1 + j - i;
         if(span > maxSpan)
            maxSpan = span;
      }
      return maxSpan;
   }
```

Edit: I realised that there is a semicolon instead of {, which is actually why it is working so now my question is, is this bad practice?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Semicolon after for loop should be removed

Comment: Now you have unbalanced braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semicolon after the For loop tells the line to stop. The loop runs, but no commands are executed. Try formatting your second for loop the same way as the first one, and it should skip those commands when nums[i] == nums[j].

```
public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {
  int maxSpan = 0;
  int span;
  int j;
  for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
  {
     for(j = nums.length - 1; nums[i] != nums[j]; j--)
     {
         span = 1 + j - i;
         if(span > maxSpan)
            maxSpan = span;
     }
  }
  return maxSpan;
}
```